# Can't assign a value to the variable

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
var readline = require('readline');
var test
rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
rl.question('What is your favorite food?', function(answer) {
 console.log('Oh, so your favorite food is ' + answer);
 test = answer
});
rl.close()

webdriverio
 .remote(options)
 .init()
 .url('http://www.google.com')
 console.log(test) //undefined, why?
```

So I don't get it why it shows me "undefined" instead of the string I enter thru terminal. Why is that?

My guess is this is not sync, but how do I make it sync?

Comment: You can't make it sync.  http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Installed: https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline-sync
2. Modified the code:

   ```
   var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
   var test

   webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://www.google.com').then(function() {
      test = readlineSync.question('What is your favorite food?'); //Honeyberry
      console.log(test) //Honeyberry
    })
   ```

Comment: If this answered your question, please make sure you accept it as the answer so that the question gets marked as answered. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffC I will, but I need to wait one more day, as it doesn't let me now.